# Change of Data in a ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view populated with some data.I need to change the data in the listview on click of a button.now the problem is the data associated with the adapter is getting changed but the same is not getting changed in the ui. but when i change the orientation from landscape to portrait,the new data is getting displayed.Can anybody suggest a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `ListAdapter`.

When changing orientation it probably works because by default on orientation change, your activity gets destroyed and recreated, also recreating the list adapter.